# Identify local account vs domain account using SID

Tags: winapi, windows-security, security-identifier

How can we know if an SID(Windows Event security identifier) belongs to a domain account or local account?

Answer (score 0):

There seems no simple general rule to distinguish local account SID and domain account SID. But there are some [well-known SIDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/well-known-sids) you can recognize.

It is sure that all local account SIDs are unique in local scope and all accounts SIDs in the same domain are unique in the domain scope. Otherwise, there will be conflicts.

Domain identifier is used to distinguish the SIDs of one domain from the SIDs for other domain in the same enterprise.

Relative identifier is used to distinguish one SID from the other in the same domain.

More references: [Machine SIDs and Domain SIDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/aaron_margosis/machine-sids-and-domain-sids), [Security identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/security-identifiers), [SID Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/sid-components).